# WMS GetMap MIME type error

Tags: wms, openlayers-2

After adding the following to the top of my index.html page

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
```

I begin to receive the following error on my GetMap WMS request

```
    Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type application/vnd.ogc.se_xml
```

Any thoughts on why this would occur are appreciated.  Here are the URL params of my WMS request:

```
    BBOX=-15130249.425402,2538320.1060898,-5869750.5745982,6461679.8939102
    FORMAT=image/png
    HEIGHT=802
    LAYERS=EFETAC-NASA_1YrBaseline_previous1
    MAXEXTENT=NaN,,,
    PROJECTION=EPSG:900913
    REQUEST=GetMap
    SERVICE=WMS
    SRS=EPSG:900913
    STYLES=
    TRANSPARENT=true
    UNITS=m
    VERSION=1.1.1
    WIDTH=1893
```

Comment: Was your map displaying correctly before the DOCTYPE change?  A returned vnd.ogc.se_xml is usually a sign that the requested resource had an exception.  As in a poorly structured request.  The error is just saying that it expected an image but got a XML instead.

Comment: since you didn't specify the return error type (Exceptions parameter) - you might not be getting the response you expected. depends on the server.

Comment: RomaH, the map was displaying correctly before the DOCTYPE change which is partly why I am perplexed.  I think I will need to go through each of the params of the getmap request and verify that they are not poorly structured as you suggested.